# libcurl process chunked response

Tags: windows, libcurl, chunked-encoding

recently i am building a program grabbing web pages from internet with libcurl, i found that when the response using chunked encoding, libcurl can't get the chunk header.then i looked into libcurl online documentations, it says chunk header tackles by WriteFunction,i am using libcurl version 2.18, and i've set a callback for CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION and CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, they've gotten anything but a single char about chunk header, is there problems about libcurl with chunk encoding? how can i make it work properly?thanks p.s. the web i am trying to grab is http://list.taobao.com/browse/cat-0.htm, it's a Chinese web site using gbk encoding

here are settings i made to cliburl

```
int32_t progress = 0;
PROCESS_ERROR(curl_easy_setopt(handle_, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, progress) == CURLE_OK);
PROCESS_ERROR(curl_easy_setopt(handle_, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1) == CURLE_OK);
PROCESS_ERROR(curl_easy_setopt(handle_, CURLOPT_DEBUGFUNCTION, &HttpSpider::curl_debug_callback) == CURLE_OK);
PROCESS_ERROR(curl_easy_setopt(handle_, CURLOPT_HTTP_TRANSFER_DECODING, 1) == CURLE_OK);
PROCESS_ERROR(curl_easy_setopt(handle_, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &HttpSpider::_ProcessRecvString) == CURLE_OK);
PROCESS_ERROR(curl_easy_setopt(handle_, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, &HttpSpider::_ProcessRecvHeader) == CURLE_OK);
PROCESS_ERROR(curl_easy_setopt(handle_, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, &HttpSpider::_ProcessRecvProgress) == CURLE_OK);
```

//here's somthing else

```
result = curl_easy_setopt(inst->handle_, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);
result = curl_easy_setopt(inst->handle_, CURLOPT_PROGRESSDATA, param);
result = curl_easy_setopt(inst->handle_, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, param);
result = curl_easy_setopt(inst->handle_, CURLOPT_WRITEHEADER, param);
result = curl_easy_setopt(inst->handle_, CURLOPT_URL, *url);

printf("/**********     HTTP GET     **********/\n");
//try to perform a post action
result = curl_easy_perform(inst->handle_);
```

callbacks are declared as required, there's chunk length in buffer passed to debugfunction , but not in writefunction, how can i get it in writefunction

Comment: Have you tried the options CURLOPT_DEBUGFUNCTION and CURLOPT_HTTP_TRANSFER_DECODING?

Comment: ah, this time i got something, there's a 4 bytes integer string in hex coming with the response body, that's the chunk length right?i got this in debug function, and when the writefunctin is called, the integer gone, can i get this length by calling a certain api?or i can only read it in debugfunction?thanks

Comment: i posted some of the code, mainly settings made to libcurl, would that be enough?

Comment: Can you tell me what "param" is declared as?

Comment: param is just a struct containing a buffer to receive response, and its length

Answer (score 0):

libcurl supports chunked encoding automatically and unconditionally without the application having to do anything.

If you don't get any data still, there's some kind of problem/bug/issue...